# How to redirect to a lightning visual force page from a quick action to open it as new tab

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I want to open a visualforce page which is working fine on lightning enabled org.
When I am opening it quick action it is opening as a pop up and does not look correct in a pop up window of quick action.

I want to open it in a new window as it was opening in classic view.
How is this achievable?

Comment: see this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm